# How to make a dynamic query without variables SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, powerbuilder

This is a dynamic query that uses a pivot statement, I want to know if it's possible to convert this Query with variables to a full Query, without variables, just the select.

```
DECLARE @dml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Months)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  DATEPART(MONTH, SOH.OrderDate) Months
         FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
         JOIN sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD ON SOH.SalesOrderId = SOD.SalesOrderId
    GROUP BY YEAR(SOH.OrderDate),
DATEPART(MONTH, SOH.OrderDate)) AS Months
 
 --Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @dml = 
  N'SELECT SalesYear, ' +@ColumnName + ' FROM
  (
  SELECT YEAR(SOH.OrderDate) AS SalesYear, 
           DATEPART(MONTH, SOH.OrderDate) Months,
           SUM(SOH.SubTotal) AS TotalSales
   FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
         JOIN sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD ON SOH.SalesOrderId = SOD.SalesOrderId
    GROUP BY YEAR(SOH.OrderDate),
    DATEPART(MONTH, SOH.OrderDate)) AS T
    PIVOT(SUM(TotalSales) 
           FOR Months IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Print @DynamicPivotQuery
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @dml
```

Comment: No, it is not, unless you can spell out all the months in advance (for example, if it's always the twelve months of the year). The best approach to take when this is not acceptable is to not pivot in T-SQL in the first place, but return the data as rows and perform the pivoting client side.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest that the only time you *should* be dynamically pivoting data is when the application layer *can't* for some reason.

Comment: Your query seems logically incorrect to me. You sum SOH.SubTotal but your query joins to the detail table - which means your sum will be incorrect as it is included once for every detail row, not just once for each order. I can see no reason why you join to the detail table at all. And powerbuilder has n-up style as well as crosstab style - why not try those? TBH your query really isn't dynamic. There are only 12 different month values.

Comment: Not a PowerBuilder question

Comment: The main reason that i'm doing this query is because my Crosstabs datawindows doesn't work. I mean, when i do the retrieve of my crosstab datawindow, The datawindow starts blinking and after that the app crash. For that reason i'm trying to do a Query to replace the Crosstab Datawindow. Idk if you were in front of a similar problem.